# Error de índice en Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

a la hora de sobreescribir un dato del dataframe con "dfdisp.iat[contador, 4] = ping", me aparece este error en la terminal:

```
index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

He intentado regenerar en índice pero no funciona

Comment: Tendrías que poner bastante más código para entender qué es lo que estás haciendo. Evidentemente `contador` está fuera del tamaño del arreglo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con la información que dejaste no te puedo dar una respuesta absoluta, sin embargo hay varias formas de hacerlo.

## Usando df.column.replace()

Una podria ser la siguiente

```
df.columnToReplace = df.columnToReplace.replace({"rowToReplace": "newValue",
                                                   "rowToReplace": "newValue"})
```

## Usando df.loc[]

Una forma mas masiva podria ser la siguiente

```
df.loc[(df.column == 'valueToReplace'),'Column']='newValue'
```

## Usando np.where()

otra forma incluso puede ser

```
df['column'] = np.where((df.column == 'valueToReplace'),'newValue',df.column)
```

## Bibliografia.

- [Pandas How to replace values based on Conditions](https://kanoki.org/2019/07/17/pandas-how-to-replace-values-based-on-conditions/)
- [Replace specific values in a dataframe column using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273067/replace-specific-values-in-a-dataframe-column-using-pandas)